# Article with mathjax to latex document

Tags: html, mathjax

I write articles in my site, and use mathjax, \( and \) for inline mode and $$ and $$ for display mode. I want to move some articles to latex document. What is the simple way to do it?

Comment: If it is just a few articles then probably the best way is just to write a new document in your normal latex editing environment, cutting and pasting in individual paragraphs from the html as needed, and fixing the markup. If you have thousands of files to convert then you want to automate it, but the difficulty is the non math part of your html, most of the mathjax can be copied across, but converting html can be easy if it is just `<h2>` and `<p>` or impossibly hard if it is a dynamic AJAX page consisting mostly of javascript.

Comment: Thanks. My html isn't a problem. What I need is automate the markup fixing, and good template for single article or for merge articles (with table of contents)

Comment: This question is too broad. Please ask specific issues that you encounter.